# Merge two data frames based time range and unique ID

Tags: r

So I have two data frames and I am trying to merge based on their unique IDs and dates, however some of the DF2 dates are sometimes one to two days off compared to DF1 for the same IDs. DF1 and DF2 are the sample dataframes and I want something like DF3 with the date column displaying either the date on DF1 or DF2

This is what I initially tried but I cannot think of a way to do joins based on dates that are not exact matches.

```
DF3 <- merge(x = DF1, y = DF2, by.x = c("ID1", "StartDate1"), 
                    by.y = c("ID2", "StartDate2"), all = FALSE)
```

Sample data:

```
DF1
ID1       StartDate1      Gender
104382    2013-09-16        M
104382    2014-02-27        F
104382    2014-07-21        F 
167623    2018-01-09        M

DF2
ID2       StartDate2      Gender
104382    2013-09-17        M
104382    2014-02-27        F
104382    2014-07-21        F
167623    2018-01-11        M
```

Desired result:

```
DF3
ID        StartDate      Gender
104382    2013-09-17       M
104382    2014-02-27       F
104382    2014-07-21       F
167623    2018-01-11       M
```

OR

```
DF3
ID        StartDate       Gender
104382    2013-09-16        M
104382    2014-02-27        F
104382    2014-07-21        F 
167623    2018-01-09        M
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the logic behind the expected output?  You seem to be taking the midpoint of the two dates, at least in a few cases.  Is that correct?

Comment: Not the midpoint it is just displaying the start date for DF2, so for DF2 some of the start dates are entered wrong by one or two days but it is supposed to be exactly the same as DF1.

Comment: you can use `sqldf` to fuzzy match on dates most likely